# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign ke y constraint fails

Tags: laravel

so i have this problem that i cannot get to solve, my solution is as follows

a user can favorite either jobs or other users, so i wrote a polymorphic relationship `one-to-many` where a user can favorite many jobs or other users.

Here is the table definition

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('favoritable_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('favoritable_type');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('default_users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

one problem is that i always get this error, whenever i try to favorite a given job,

the job with id works perfectly, but the second wont work

this runs ok

```
DefaultUser::first()->favoriteJobs()->save(Job::first())
```

but this

```
DefaultUser::first()->favoriteJobs()->save(Job::find(2))
```

gives the following error

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
fails (`dwarozh_jobs`.`favorites`, CONSTRAINT `favorites_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `default_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: inser
t into `favorites` (`favoritable_id`, `favoritable_type`, `user_id`) values (1, App/Models/Job, 2))'
```

`CanFavorite.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Concerns;

use App\Models\Job;

trait CanFavoriteJobs {
    public function favoriteJobs()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Job::class, 'favoritable', 'favorites', 'favoritable_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

thank you for your answer.

Comment: What is the difference between resulting records from `Job::first()` and `Job::find(2)`?

Comment: this im trying to add two different records, like a user having  multiple favorites

Comment: As per the error the `user_id` is 2 and `favoritable_id` is 1 where as it should be the other way around DeaultUser::first() should normally have id 1 while Job::find(2) should definitely have id= 2 which means favoritable_id should have corresponding value as 2 in the INSERT statement

Comment: where i made a mistake if u know ?

Comment: try swapping the last 2 arguments to the `morphedByMany` call in `favoriteJobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario: A user can favorite another user and/or a job.

Migration for `favorites` table

```php
class CreateFavoritesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'favoritable_id', 'favoritable_type']);
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('favoritable_id');
            $table->string('favoritable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('favorites');
    }
}
```

Favorite Eloquent model - to get some relational functionality

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Favorite extends Model
{
    //use HasFactory;

    public function favoritables()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('favoritable');
    }
}
```

Trait to provide functionality for marking a record favorite and favorites relation.

```php
namespace App;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

trait Favoritable
{
    /**
     * Get all favorites associated with the model.
     */
    public function favorites(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'favoritable', 'favorites')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Mark the model record as favorite
     */
    public function favorite(?User $user = null): void
    {
        $user = $user ?: auth()->user();

        $this->favorites()->attach($user);
    }
}
```

Make the User as well as Job model use the trait

```php
use App\Favoritable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Model
{    
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, Favoritable;

    //$fillable, $hidden, $casts etc

    public function favoritesForUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class, 'user_id', 'id')->where('favoritable_type', 'App\Models\User');
    }

    public function favoritesForJobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class, 'user_id', 'id')->where('favoritable_type', 'App\Models\Job');
    }
}
```

Job (Eloquent) Model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Favoritable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Favoritable;

    //Model class definition
}
```

Now to mark as favorite a Job or User - by authenticated user - logged in user

```
//Mark the first Job as favorited by currently logged in user
$job = Job::first();
$job->favorite();

//Mark the User with an id of 45 favorited by currently logged in user
$user = User::find(45);
$user->favorite();
```